# Using a wildcard in awk with references to file

Tags: awk

Using awk, I want to print all lines that have a string in the first column that starts with /dev/vda

I tried the following, but obviously `*` does not work as a wildcard in awk:

```
awk '$1=="/dev/vda/*" {print $3}'
```

Is this possible in awk?

Comment: *obviously `*` does not work as a wildcard in awk* - `awk` comprehend [POSIX regular expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

For string matching there is the `index()` function:

```
awk 'index($1, "/dev/vda") == 1'
```

The function returns the starting position of a substring, which must be 1 if it's at the beginning.

> `*` does not work as a wildcard

This is true – awk does not use shell-like patterns, although `*` may appear as a regex metacharacter (where it would match zero or more repetitions of the the previous character).

Comment: That should be `index($1, "/dev/vda/")` so it doesn't match `/dev/vdabob` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1~/^\/dev\/vda\// {print $3}'
```

`awk` has wildcards in regular expressions, not in string equality checks.

Technically the `*` is not a wildcard in a regex, it's a quantifier.  The regex equivalent of the wildcard `*` of *any number of any character* would be `.*`.

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly what i need but very close:
awk '$1~/\/dev\/vda\/*/ {print $3}'

Comment: Btw, @NicoCarabelli , for a "substring match" we don't actually need an asterisk at all.  Where you placed it  it makes the expression say "any string that begins with `/dev/vda` followed by ZERO or more occurrences of `/` ..

Comment: you need `^` anchor to enforce "starts with", otherwise any match will be printed. With this change you can remove the field reference as well.

Comment: Cheers @karakfa - I'll patch that ... even though (from a purely pragmatic approach) the likelihood of `/dev/vda` showing up anywhere else in a linux directory structure is pretty remote.

Comment: In this case I'd be tempted to use `$1~"^/dev/vda/"` to avoid all the escaping.

Comment: @NicoCarabelli with respect to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051080/using-a-wildcard-in-awk-with-references-to-file#comment118518478_67051094), `/\/*/` means "zero-or-more repetitions of `/`" - it's highly unlikely that that's what you really want.